# SQL field add date change format to YYYYMMDD

Tags: sql, datefield

I have one field for date contains year and months. Field name new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian.  Exmaple of data 199110 (Format:YYYYMM). I want to add date to set a new format require are (YYYYMMDD).
For the available data Can I add date follow end of the month for that month. 
Example 199101 = 19910130 OR 199102 = 19910228 OR 199103 = 19910231

This code is not work for me

> SELECT DMSTAG.dbo.TEMP_AKAUN_MARA.new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian
>       CASE 
>           WHEN RIGHT(new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian,2) = 01 THEN CONCAT(new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian,31)
>           WHEN RIGHT(new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian,2) = 02 THEN CONCAT(new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian,28)
>           WHEN RIGHT(new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian,2) = 03 THEN CONCAT(new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian,31)
>           WHEN RIGHT(new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian,2) = 04 THEN CONCAT(new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian,30)            WHEN
>   RIGHT(new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian,2) = 05 THEN
>   CONCAT(new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian,31)        WHEN
>   RIGHT(new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian,2) = 06 THEN
>   CONCAT(new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian,30)        WHEN
>   RIGHT(new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian,2) = 07 THEN
>   CONCAT(new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian,31)        WHEN
>   RIGHT(new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian,2) = 08 THEN
>   CONCAT(new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian,31)            WHEN
>   RIGHT(new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian,2) = 09 THEN
>   CONCAT(new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian,30)        WHEN
>   RIGHT(new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian,2) = 10 THEN
>   CONCAT(new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian,31)        WHEN
>   RIGHT(new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian,2) = 11 THEN
>   CONCAT(new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian,30)        WHEN
>   RIGHT(new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian,2) = 12 THEN
>   CONCAT(new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian,31)
>       END AS newdate  FROM [dbo].[TEMP_AKAUN_MARA]

Comment: what is the schema of your table?

Comment: Those aren't date fields, those are text fields.   You would be well advised to correct your schema and make date fields date fields.

Comment: @MUHD MAN, please the update on my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT id,crse_date,
    CASE 
        WHEN RIGHT(crse_date,2) = 01 THEN CONCAT(crse_date,31)
        WHEN RIGHT(crse_date,2) = 02 THEN CONCAT(crse_date,28)
        WHEN RIGHT(crse_date,2) = 03 THEN CONCAT(crse_date,31)   
        WHEN RIGHT(crse_date,2) = 04 THEN CONCAT(crse_date,30)       
    END AS newdate
 FROM yourtable


After you alter your table. Here is new query for your problem
Takenote : your field name is not advisable

SELECT new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian, 
    CASE
    WHEN RIGHT(new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian,2) = 01 THEN CONCAT(new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian,31)
    WHEN RIGHT(new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian,2) = 02 THEN CONCAT(new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian,28) 
    WHEN RIGHT(new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian,2) = 03 THEN CONCAT(new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian,31)
    WHEN RIGHT(new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian,2) = 04 THEN CONCAT(new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian,30) 
    WHEN RIGHT(new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian,2) = 05 THEN CONCAT(new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian,31) 
    WHEN RIGHT(new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian,2) = 06 THEN CONCAT(new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian,30) 
    WHEN RIGHT(new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian,2) = 07 THEN CONCAT(new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian,31) 
    WHEN RIGHT(new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian,2) = 08 THEN CONCAT(new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian,31) 
    WHEN RIGHT(new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian,2) = 09 THEN CONCAT(new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian,30) 
    WHEN RIGHT(new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian,2) = 10 THEN CONCAT(new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian,31) 
    WHEN RIGHT(new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian,2) = 11 THEN CONCAT(new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian,30) 
    WHEN RIGHT(new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian,2) = 12 THEN CONCAT(new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian,31)
    END AS newdate 
FROM TEMP_AKAUN_MARA
```

Comment: I have try but not working
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.

Comment: I have tried that code in my mysql and it works fine, may I know your exact columns in table?

Comment: Table : dbo.TEMP_AKAUN_MARA
Field : new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian

Comment: Is it really your field names? I thought your field for date is crse_date

Comment: Sory Mr Edrich. I already rename CRSE_DATE to new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian. 
So i write --> 
WHEN RIGHT(new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian,2) = 01 THEN CONCAT(new_TarikhSebenarTamatPengajian,31)

Comment: Ah I see, There is no problem regarding that as long you change also with the query but that fieldnames are not advisable. can you comment the full query after the changes?

Comment: @MUHDMAN you missed the comma(,) before CASE, please see the update on my answer above.

Comment: Error here: Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the concat operation.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your column name is DateWithOutMonth :

```
Select Convert(nvarchar(8), Dateadd(day, -1, Dateadd(month, 1, Convert(datetime, DateWithOutMonth + '01'))) , 112) 
from your table
```

Code explained :

- first, add `01` to the end of your date value, so the value will always is the beginning of a month
- convert the value to date time type
- add 1 month into the newly converted value
- minus one day from the new ly added value -> we have the end date of the month

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this to acheive your functionality.

I hope this will help you

```
    SELECT   
      CASE
        WHEN CRSE_DATE = '199101' THEN '19910130'
        WHEN CRSE_DATE = '199102' THEN '19910228'
        WHEN CRSE_DATE = '199103' THEN '19910231'
      END 
    FROM 
    table_name
```